# Spring Boot, some asset files in public/static folder cannot be found in browser resulting in 404

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am running into a strange issue in my Spring Boot Maven project.

Into the `/public/assets/` folder, all resources can be found in the browser except some css or js files generating a `404 HTTP error`
Everything is set in my config file, specially `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` is extended.
Because I am using `Spring Security` dependency, here is a portion of code that handles assets files

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web
        .ignoring()
        .antMatchers("/assets/**", "/files/**");
}
```

Therefore, in the image below, highlighted files are not loaded.
[image]

Note that this strange behavior only happened today, everything was working as expected the last time I ran the project.

Any idea what I mess or did ?

Comment: Have you checked that css taking proper path by inspect element ?

Comment: @M123456 what you mean ?

Comment: I faced this problem previously that time I've checked that css path by network tab of inspect element in browser. it's taking different path of css. it added some mapping name at  first of that css file path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that some logical errors may impact page generation without any *stacktrace*.

In my case, I added a `JPA Repository` extending `CrudRepository`. I had no errors in the application execution but for some reason my frontend was impacted. As soon as I removed the repository in question everything went back to normal.

WEIRD !